# Backbone.js view inheritance

Tags: inheritance, backbone.js

I have a view called `Pannel` which is just a background with a close button. I want to extend that view to one called `PannelAdvanced`. How would I do that with backbone.js?

Right now all the examples have `Backbone.View.Extend` but those just extend `Backbone.View`; I want to extend my `PannelView`.

Comment: It works exactly the same way - `Panel.extend({ ... })`

Comment: I have my Panel = Backbone.View.extend() then I have advancedPanel = Panel.extend() but when I do a console log for a variable in the initialize method of Panel inside of advancedPanel it shows up as undefined.

Comment: Can I just call Panel.extend() without instantiating Panel first.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The easiest way to inherit a view is to do what other people have already suggested in the comments:

```
var Pannel = Backbone.View.extend({
});

var PannelAdvanced = Pannel.extend({
});
```

But like you've noted in your comments, if you have an initialize method in Pannel, then it won't be called if you also have an initialize method in PannelAdvanced, so you have to call Pannel's initialize method explicitly:

```
var Pannel = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function(options){
      console.log('Pannel initialized');
      this.foo = 'bar';
   }
});

var PannelAdvanced = Pannel.extend({
   initialize: function(options){
      Pannel.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [options])
      console.log('PannelAdvanced initialized');
      console.log(this.foo); // Log: bar
   }
});
```

It's a bit ugly because if you have a lot of Views that inherit from Pannel, then you'll have to remember to call Pannel's initialize from all of them.  Even worse, if Pannel doesn't have an initialize method now but you choose to add it in the future, then you'll need to go to all of the inherited classes in the future and make sure they call Pannel's initialize.  So here's an alternative way to define Pannel so that your inherited views don't need to call Pannel's initialize method:

```
var Pannel = function (options) {

    // put all of Panel's initialization code here
    console.log('Pannel initialized');
    this.foo = 'bar';

    Backbone.View.apply(this, [options]);
};

_.extend(Pannel.prototype, Backbone.View.prototype, {

    // put all of Panel's methods here. For example:
    sayHi: function () {
        console.log('hello from Pannel');
    }
});

Pannel.extend = Backbone.View.extend;


// other classes inherit from Panel like this:
var PannelAdvanced = Pannel.extend({

    initialize: function (options) {
        console.log('PannelAdvanced initialized');
        console.log(this.foo);
    }
});

var pannelAdvanced = new PannelAdvanced(); //Log: Pannel initialized, PannelAdvanced initialized, bar
pannelAdvanced.sayHi(); // Log: hello from Pannel
```

Comment: This pattern doesn't work with events being declared in both child and parent as the parent's events key in the dict is overwritten by the child's when you call `var PannelAdvanced = Pannel.extend({events:{...}})`.  You can declare a parentsEvents key in the parent, and call then `this.delgateEvents(this.parentEvents)` in the parent constructor but then due to [this line](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1310) in backbone, they will again be dropped due to the child view.

Comment: Actually you can do it.  Declare the child events in a childEvents key or whatever, then in the parent, declare an `events` function with:  `return _.extend({"click .parentClass": "parentFunction"}, this.childEvents)`

Comment: Using `_super` is not the best choice. https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/pull/787#issuecomment-14327908

Comment: I agree.  It's better to use prototype.  I updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 29):

This is one of the reasons I like using Coffeescript so much.  Things like inheritance are so much nicer.  To piggyback @JohnnyO's correct answer, I can say the same thing in Coffeescript:

```
class Panel extends Backbone.View
    initialize: ->
        console.log 'Panel initialized'
        @foo = 'bar'

class PanelAdvanced extends Panel
    initialize: ->
        super
        console.log 'PanelAdvanced initialized'
        console.log @foo
```

Comment: I translated that to javascript just to see if I get it write:

http://jsfiddle.net/7qssz/

`super` becomes `Panel.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work while passing arguments. They don't show up in `this.options`.

Comment: @Maletor: What version of Backbone are you using?  It was added around the 0.9.9 version or something like that.

Comment: Works. @NicoGranelli your code is not 1:1 translation from Coffeescript. Please [see and run the code in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yosubifewu/2/edit?html,js,output). Select _Convert to Javascript_, from the CoffeeScript popup.

Answer (score 8):

To piggyback further a bit:

I liked @JohnnyO's approach but wanted to confirm that a resulting view was still capable of doing everything it's supposed to. Given his approach, I didn't suspect there would be any issues, but I wanted to be a bit more certain.

So, I took a minute and adapted the [Backbone.js Views test suite](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/test/view.js) to the multiple inheritance technique @JohnnyO proposes.

You can run the results at http://jsfiddle.net/dimadima/nPWuG/. **All tests pass.**

My base and extended views:

```
var RegularView = function (options) {
  // All of this code is common to both a `RegularView` and `SuperView`
  // being constructed.
  this.color = options && (options.color || 'Green');

  // If execution arrives here from the construction of
  // a `SuperView`, `Backbone.View` will call `initialize`
  // that belongs to `SuperView`. This happens because here
  // `this` is `SuperView`, and `Backbone.View`, applied with
  // the current `this` calls `this.initialize.apply(this, arguments)`
  Backbone.View.apply(this, arguments)
};

RegularView.extend = Backbone.View.extend;

_.extend(RegularView.prototype, Backbone.View.prototype, {
  // Called if a `RegularView` is constructed`,
  // Not called if a `SuperView` is constructed.
  initialize: function () {
    console.log('RegularView initialized.');
  },

  say_hi: function() {
    console.log('Regular hi!');
  }

});

var SuperView = RegularView.extend({
  // Called if a `SuperView` is constructed`,
  // Not called if a `RegularView` is constructed.
  initialize: function(options) {
    console.log('SuperView initialized.')
  },

  say_hi: function() {
    console.log('Super hi!');
  }
})
```

For the test suite, I grabbed the [latest views tests from GitHub](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/test/view.js) and replaced occurrences of `Backbone.View` with `RegularView`. The tests then use `RegularView` and the results of `RegularView.extend()` to make sure both do what they're supposed to.