# Backbone.js view inheritance - How to extend the ChildViews?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to get my child views to inherit from the Parent view but not quite sure how to do it.I did find an answer to a similar problem [Backbone.js view inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735133/backbone-js-view-inheritance), but dont really know how to implement it in my code.Any advice much appreciated.thanks

```
win.MyApp = {
    Models: {
        Model_1 : Backbone.Model.extend({

        }),
        Model_2 : Backbone.Model.extend({

        }),
        Model_3 : Backbone.Model.extend({

        })
    },
    Views: {
        ViewParent : Backbone.View.extend({

        }),
        ViewChild_1 : Backbone.View.extend({

        }),
        ViewChild_2 : Backbone.View.extend({

        })
    },
    Routers: {
        MainRouter : Backbone.Router.extend({

        })
    },
    init: function(){
        router = new this.Routers.MainRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    MyApp.init()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the Classes you created thanks to Backbone: those also have the extend method.

```
var Parent = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Child = Parent.extend({});
```

[Simple example here](http://jsfiddle.net/zJuHL/)

If I remember well the Backbone's code, the child's methods will erase the parent's one if there is a conflict (OOP logic).