# unbinding children of backbone view

Tags: backbone.js, unbind

I've got a backbone calendar, and each day has a bunch of options. The user only sees one day at a time.

So when the user selects to go to the next or previous day, I call the `MyApp.Views.ShowDay` to redraw the day.

the `ShowDay` view calls a few sub-views `MyApp.Views.Hours`.
I need to unbind the hours from the old day when I create a new day, but that is causing nothing but errors.

The way I'm trying to do it is

```
MyApp.Views.Showday = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
             "click div.change_day":"change_day"
    },

    change_day: function(){
      MyApp.Views.Hours.unbind(); //I've tried off(), off, remove() as well

    }

});
```

Is this not the way to unbind children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly unbind the event handlers from the event. See this answer to another SO question, paying specific attention to the `bindTo` and `unbindFromAll` functions:

[Backbone.js : repopulate or recreate the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567404/backbone-js-repopulate-or-recreate-the-view/7607853#7607853)

Comment: thanks Derick, I had actually read your article on Los Techies regarding your binding technique, but i was hoping for something <gulp> simpler. I'm giving this a try now.

Comment: unfortunately, there isn't anything simpler. Backbone takes a hands-off approach to this, and lets us either shoot ourselves in the foot or write the extra code ourselves. FWIW: https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/backbone.marionette.js#L463-488 just copy & paste the code from there and use _.extend to mix it in to your own stuff. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try MyApp.Views.Hours.remove(). This removes the view and its elements from the dom and tears down any event handlers in the process. Then recreate the hours view

Comment: it could be because of the way I wrote my nesting, but this also didn't allow me to add another child after removing it. I had tried that earlier.