# After backbone model is removed from collection, destroyed, and remove from DOM, anymore zombie left to be handled?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

From what I have read http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/ and [Backbone.js : repopulate or recreate the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567404/backbone-js-repopulate-or-recreate-the-view) I learned that hidden view should be unbind'ed from events.

How about removing a model?  After calling

- `remove()` on Collection
- `destroy()` on the Model
- `remove()` on View

Shall I call `off()` on Model as the last step?

Assuming no one else hold a reference to the instance of the model, is that the end of zombie killing?  The view might still have a reference to the model, should the view's `this.model` set to `null`?

Anymore memory leak?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the annoted source , it's pretty clear what model.destroy() does , **it doesnt delete the model** , just request the server to delete a REST resource. if you want to get rid of the model in your script you can create a destroy function to your view that will erase any objects you want to get rid of.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html

regarding events , i'm not sure , but yeah you could call off , you could also spy the internal event object of the model in your browser dev tools to see if it still exists after you delete the model.

Comment: how do I "spy the internal event object"?  Say, Chrome or FF?

Comment: put a breakpoint after the model is created , and you should be able to watch the event object in Chrome for instance , go to the script tab , there is a watch menu where you can add spies.