# What's the difference between event EventAggregator and EventBinder in Backbone Marionette?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-events

From the docs in [Marionette.EventAggregator](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.eventaggregator.md) and [Marionette.EventBinder](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.eventbinder.md) the code is quite the same. I suppose there's a difference I'm missing, what is it? When to use each of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary difference was intent. An EventAggregator's intent is explained in these articles:

http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html

http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2009/07/22/braindump-on-the-event-aggregator-pattern/

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/19/references-routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating-views-in-backbone-js/

The EventBinder's purpose was to manage dependencies in event bindings, as first described by Johnny Oshika here: [Backbone.js : repopulate or recreate the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567404/backbone-js-repopulate-or-recreate-the-view/7607853#7607853)

...

Moving forward with Marionette and Backbone v0.9.9, though, EventBinder is now obsolete because Backbone.Events now includes the `listenTo` and `stopListening` methods. The `EventAggregator` is taking over anything that Backbone.Events doesn't cover. This is for Marionette v1.0-rc3 and beyond, though. If you're still using Marionette v1.0-rc2 or previous, you'll still need the EventBinder.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the event's addition on 0.9.9 so +1 for the good news.