# this.remove() on backbone view makes el disappear

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

Referring to this post: [Backbone.js : repopulate or recreate the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567404/backbone-js-repopulate-or-recreate-the-view)

I'm basically using what has the most votes, but not the accepted answer in showing views from my router.

So I essentially call

```
this.unbind();
this.remove();
```

The problem I'm having is I have a left side navigation panel, and then on the right I have my content.  It looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
            // nav bar stuff
        </div>
        <div class="span10">
            <div id="content-container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when I call this.remove() on a view, it basically leaves me with:

```
<div class="span10"></div>
```

The div container disappears.  I didn't know what the best way to either remove the backbone view, or insert the `<div id="content-container"></div>` was.  I guess when I dispose of my views, and after calling remove(), I could look in the DOM and insert the content-container, but it seems like there should be a better way.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove):

> **remove** `view.remove()`
>
> Removes a view from the DOM, and calls *stopListening* to remove any bound events that the view has *listenTo*'d.

[The implementation](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.0/backbone.js#L1024) is pretty much a strait transliteration of the English into JavaScript:

```
remove: function() {
  this.$el.remove();
  this.stopListening();
  return this;
}
```

That `this.$el.remove()` call removes the element from the DOM.

Your problem is that you're using this as your view's `el`:

```
<div id="content-container"></div>
```

so `view.remove()` deletes your `#content-container`.

There are solutions:

1. Let the view create its own `el` and then put that *inside* the `#content-container`.
2. Override the `remove` method:

   ```
   remove: function() {
       this.unbind();
       this.stopListening();
       // No this.$el.remove() since we don't own the `el`
       return this;
   }
   ```

Comment: upvoted. in my opinion remove() by default should *not* remove the DOM element from the DOM. it's stupid. remove() should have args. remove(true) should delete the DOM element. I was confused for a couple days about why my new Views would not show up after removing the previous view. Probably not the only one.

Comment: @AlexMills: I have a better time when views create and manage their own `el`s so the default `remove` behavior works for me. If you're binding to existing elements then you have to override `remove` anyway so that the view can remove its event delegation or you'll have memory leaks, zombies, and puzzling duplicated events. Instead of an argument, `remove` might be better off checking to see if the view created its own `el` and either remove the node or undelegate the events as appropriate; there are holes in this approach though.

Comment: the docs need an update. it says "remove view from the DOM", it does not say "remove DOM element from DOM." this tricky shit "this.$el.remove();" inside remove() is F-ing up many people's lives. As you say, mu, you will pretty much have to override/roll your own remove no matter what. However IMO the default is wrong. and the docs are misleading.

Comment: @AlexMills Sorry but you're complaining to the wrong person. I'd say that allowing a view to be bound to an existing element is F-ing up many people's lives and shouldn't be allowed but it isn't my call.

Comment: I really don't see how adding and deleting DOM elements on the fly should be default behavior, but I haven't been doing web development very long

Comment: @AlexMills: Nothing to do with web development specifically, just basic software cleanliness: don't mess with anything that doesn't belong to you. The caller (generally a router in Backbone) should be creating views, adding their `el`s to appropriate containers on the page, and then calling `remove` on them to kill them off.

Comment: mu I do see what youre saying and I see how perhaps backbone could distinguish between a view creating its own el or not. but on that point! this is where the lopsided behavior comes in! i attached a view to an existing el, so when i remove the view it seems unlikely that I'd want to remove that el. that would be lopsided behavior which is exaclty what backbone is doing by default. to this minute i still cant tell you how to create a new el with backbone.

Comment: @AlexMills: Have you read the Backbone documentation? The [`View#el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) docs cover that.

Comment: thanks mu, do you have a recommendation as for a child view system - do you recommend Backbone.Marionette, or another system? Could you point me to a place that describes how to best handle child views?